# After a coroutine scope is canceled, can it still be used again?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

When we have a coroutine scope, when it is canceled, can it be used again?

e.g. for the below, when I have `scope.cancel`, the `scope.launch` no longer work

```
    @Test
    fun testingLaunch() {
        val scope = MainScope()
        runBlocking {
            scope.cancel()
            scope.launch {
                try {
                    println("Start Launch 2")
                    delay(200)
                    println("End Launch 2")
                } catch (e: CancellationException) {
                    println("Cancellation Exception")
                }
            }.join()

            println("Finished")
        }
    }
```

Similarly, when we have `scope.cancel` before `await` called,

```
    @Test
    fun testingAsync() {
        val scope = MainScope()
        runBlocking {
            scope.cancel()
            val defer = scope.async {
                try {
                    println("Start Launch 2")
                    delay(200)
                    println("End Launch 2")
                } catch (e: CancellationException) {
                    println("Cancellation Exception")
                }
            }
            defer.await()
            println("Finished")
        }
    }
```

It will not execute. Instead, it will crash with

```
kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException: Job was cancelled
; job=SupervisorJobImpl{Cancelled}@39529185
    at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.cancel(JobSupport.kt:1579)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScopeKt.cancel(CoroutineScope.kt:217)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScopeKt.cancel$default(CoroutineScope.kt:215)
    at com.example.coroutinerevise.CoroutineExperiment$testingAsync$1.invokeSuspend(CoroutineExperiment.kt:241)
    at |b|b|b(Coroutine boundary.|b(|b)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DeferredCoroutine.await$suspendImpl(Builders.common.kt:101)
    at com.example.coroutinerevise.CoroutineExperiment$testingAsync$1.invokeSuspend(CoroutineExperiment.kt:254)
Caused by: kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException: Job was cancelled; job=SupervisorJobImpl{Cancelled}@39529185
    at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.cancel(JobSupport.kt:1579)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScopeKt.cancel(CoroutineScope.kt:217)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScopeKt.cancel$default(CoroutineScope.kt:215)
    at com.example.coroutinerevise.CoroutineExperiment$testingAsync$1.invokeSuspend(CoroutineExperiment.kt:241)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
```

Is it true, a canceled coroutine scope cannot be used for `launch` or `async` anymore?

Comment: Kind of. As `CoroutineScope` is just a holder for a `CoroutineContext`, which in turn must have a `Job` as part of it. See the `CoroutineScope()` function implementation and notice a `Job` is added if none found in the context. When you call `cancel()` on the `CoroutineScope`, it's cancelling the internal `Job`. So to reuse the `CoroutineScope`, a new `Job` must be added to the context.

Comment: After testing, AFAIK, you do need to create a new `CoroutineScope` as the underlying `CoroutineContext` cannot be updated.

Comment: That's sad. Not sure if that is also applicable to `lifecycleScope`?

Comment: I don’t think lifecycleScope is intended to be manually cancelled. It’s called “lifecycle” because it’s life is automatically managed to match a lifecycle. Cancelling it manually would disrupt that.

Answer (score 30):

Instead of using `CoroutineScope` for cancelling all of the launched jobs in it, you may want to use the underlying `CoroutineContext` with its `cancelChildren()` method which doesn't affect the `Job` state (which is not true for plain `cancel()` method) and allows to continue launching new coroutines after being invoked.

Comment: Can you show in code how to access the underlying CoroutineContext and use it's cancelChildren() method?

Comment: scope.coroutineContext.cancelChildren()

Answer (score 10):

Following up on @Alex Bonel response.

For example you have a method like

```
fun doApiCall() {
 viewModelScope.launch { 
     // do api call here
 }
}
```

You can call `doApiCall()` again and again

```
viewModelScope.coroutineContext.cancelChildren()
doApiCall()
```

Calling `doApiCall()` will not have any effect.

```
viewModelScope.coroutineContext.cancel()
doApiCall() // would not call
```

Answer (score 4):

I am using that in compose and it is slightly different.

1. Define coroutine scope in compose

`val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()`

2. Launch coroutine

`coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {  //Perform your operation }`

3. Cancel all coroutines that belong to coroutineScope

`coroutineScope.coroutineContext.cancelChildren()`

Answer (score 0):

Related to lifecycleScope comment above, I'm not sure how common cancellation like this would be in practice?  fwiw something like following will work:

```
val scope = MainScope()
runBlocking {
    val job1 = scope.launch {
        try {
            println("Start Launch 1")
            delay(200)
            println("End Launch 1")
        } catch (e: CancellationException) {
            println("Cancellation Exception")
        }
    }

    job1.cancel()
    val job2 = scope.launch {
        try {
            println("Start Launch 2")
            delay(200)
            println("End Launch 2")
        } catch (e: CancellationException) {
            println("Cancellation Exception")
        }
    }
    job2.join()

    println("Finished")
}
```

This particular example will print

```
Start Launch 1
Cancellation Exception
Start Launch 2
End Launch 2
Finished
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to collect the event just once and then stop listening. I came up with this solution:

```
/**
* Collect the value once and stop listening (one-time events)
*/
suspend fun <T> Flow<T>.collectOnce(action: suspend (value: T) -> Unit) {
  try {
    coroutineScope {
      collectLatest {
        action(it)
        this@coroutineScope.cancel()
      }
    }
  } catch (e: CancellationException) { }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
  myStateFlow.collectOnce {
    // Code to run
  }
}
```